# Scrape data from Google

Tags: data-acquisition

my question is general. 
I would like to search a term on Google and scrape all the results, including the dates of publishing, if there are.
I know that it is possible to scrape a website - following the policy, of course!, and not breaking the rules - by using Python or other softwares. 
Is it possible to do this in Mathematica?

[image]

**UPDATE:** By using `ServiceConnect`, I got this output:

```
results = ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", "Search", {"Query" -> "machine learning", "FileFormat" -> Entity["FileFormat", "PDF-1"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/GoogleCustomSearch.html).

Comment: I tried to use what you suggested, but it download an empty object (please see the post)

Comment: If this does not work for you `results = 
 ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", 
  "Search", {"Query" -> "machine learning", MaxItems -> 10}]` then most likely the credentials are not setup correctly. Follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#prerequisites) to get the search engine id and api key.